# How to construct types in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, I want to construct a `Type` object (from `java.lang.reflect`) that represent a complex type i.e. if I have classes `Foo.class` and `Goo.class` I want a `Type` object that represent `Foo<Goo>`.

I know that in [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for example, it is done using [`constructParametricType()`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/index.html) method of `org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory` class, but it returns a `org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType` and I want a `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

Comment: Why don't you use Jackson then?

Comment: I need something generic, so that clients can pass a type and my code will deserialize it to the specified type while being able to use any third-party serializer available.

Comment: How are you planning to use this `Type` object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sun.reflect.generics` APIs, though this may not be portable:

```
class Foo<T> {}
class Goo {}

class Example {
    public void parameterizedTypeExample() {
        final GenericsFactory f = CoreReflectionFactory.make(
            Example.class,
            ClassScope.make(Example.class)
        );

        final ParameterizedType p = f.makeParameterizedType(
            /* declaration: */ Foo.class,
            /* typeArgs: */ new Type[] { Goo.class },
            /* owner: */ null
        );

        // System.out.println(p) => "Foo<Goo>"
    }
}
```

But, really, I find the Java reflection APIs to be pretty inept, especially when dealing with generics.  I've written [an alternate API](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/) based on .NET's `System.Reflection` that makes dealing with Java types a bit more uniform.  Depending on your needs, you may find it useful.  Using it is a bit simpler:

```
Type<Foo<Goo>> fooGoo = Type.of(Foo.class)
                            .makeGenericType(Type.of(Goo.class));
```

Note that `Type` here is **not** a `java.reflect.Type`, but the class `procyon-reflection` uses to represent any type ("reference" classes, primitives, type variables, wildcards, etc.).

However, I think I will add an `asJavaType()` method to my `Type` class that will return the corresponding `java.reflect.Type`, as that seems like a worthwhile feature to have :).

Comment: Why it may not be portable?

Comment: I think that anything in the `sun.*` packages constitutes an "internal" API to Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK.  They're not officially supported and may not be included in all Java runtimes.

Comment: But if I manage dependencies with Maven, then any component that Includes dependency to my component, will transitively import `sun`'s dependency, won't it?

Comment: The `sun.*` classes do not exist in any Maven artifact that I'm aware of.  They are included in the Sun/Oracle JDK and, I believe, OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

you can call getGenericType() from java.lang.reflect.Field if you have a field object reflecting a declared "Foo field;"